# Alternatively Position Div

Tags: html, css

I am currently coding a home page that will include links to products, news and social media. What I am looking to do is have the social media field appear every two but never below its self like this;

[image: Target Result]

The actual result I am getting though is

Social | Product | Social | News

Social | News | Social | Product

What is the best way to achieve this?

Edit: At the moment I am fetching each 'cell' from a JSON array and appending it to the container. Because the number of cells is dynamic I can't simply append Social, Product, Social, Post, Social and repeat because the code would be huge and I would end up with duplicates of Social.

Comment: Please post your code so we can see what you have tried.

Comment: you haven't explained exactly what you want to do.  You need to think about the design from all screen sizes ,  if you want the squares to stay a certain size and show 4 across on larger screens then 3 on smaller then 2 on smaller then you might need ot re-order them, if oyu just want the size to stretch and show al 4 across on vertical phone view then that is just setting width to a percent

Comment: @Matthew At the moment it is writing the divs to the main container, as there is a dynamic length of the number of 'cells' that can be displayed I can't keep running the fetch code for each cell. This is just for the desktop site on mobile it will display them in a list

Comment: I like @Matthew 's idea: "Please post your code so we can see what you have tried." - Your additional information is even more confusing. Explain the whole process - and what you expect to happen. So far, it sounds like - "I want this to be different but only in a certain way."

Comment: @Alex you said that each box is being entered in dynamically. How are they being entered dynamically?? Are you using a JavaScript API or PHP? If you cannot post the html code, then post the code that creates the dynamic html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stagger your elements when you create them with an odd number of elements per row.

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="news">
  </div>
  <div class="social">
  </div>
  <div class="product">
  </div>
  <div class="social">
  </div>
  <div class="news">
  </div>
  <!-- second row -->
  <div class="social">
  </div>
   <div class="product">
  </div>
  <div class="social">
  </div>
  <div class="news">
  </div>
  <div class="social">
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you can use flex to get them wrapping.

```
#container {
  max-width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.news, .social, .product {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.news {
  background-color: blue;
}
.social {
  background-color: red;
}
.product {
  background-color: green;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7ep3skds/